# No such file iostream.h when including

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to get iostream.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698267/where-to-get-iostream-h)

I am trying to compile the AVL tree example [here](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/bradapp/ftp/src/libs/C++/AvlTrees.html). But when I typed make it says fatal error: iostream.h: no such file. I think the code is implemented using c library since it ended with .h but why couldn't it find this file? Is it depreciated?

Comment: I see that code was written in 1989.

Answer (score 5):

Try `#include <iostream>` instead.

Comment: I wonder is just changing the name would suffice. Do they both have the same implementation? One is std so I would have to resolve the namespaces first.

Answer (score 2):

In the new compiler, you do not need .h suffix use below instead.

```
#include <iostream>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is deprecated. STL file names have no extension, so you should write `#include <iostream>` instead.