# fatal error: iostream.h no such file or directory

Tags: c++, codeblocks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No such file iostream.h when including](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338584/no-such-file-iostream-h-when-including)

Even after naming the source file with .cpp extension. my compiler gives this error, both in command prompt and Codeblocks. How can I fix this issue?

```
#include <iostream.h>


int main(){

    cout<<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `#include <iostream>`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

That header doesn't exist in standard C++. It was part of some pre-1990s compilers, but it is certainly not part of C++.

Use `#include <iostream>` instead. And all the library classes are in the `std::` namespace, for ex­am­ple `std::cout`.

Also, throw away any book or notes that mention the thing you said.

Comment: 1970's?. was Bjarne still in high-school back then ?

Comment: @J99: I never exaggerate, not in the entire history of the universe.

Comment: I think the original streams library was invented by some Jerry Schwartz in the early or mid-80s. For some reason I have 1984 stuck in my head, but I am too lazy to get D&E down from the shelf where it rots and check this.

Answer (score 11):

Using standard C++ calling (note that you should use namespace *std* for *cout* or add *using namespace std;*)

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minus the part about "using namespace std." You should almost never do that.

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}

Answer (score 9):

You should be using `iostream` *without* the `.h`.

Early implementations used the `.h` variants but the standard mandates the more modern style.