# C++ - gcc o n Fedora Linux

Tags: c++, gcc, fedora

I'm trying to run a simple *Hello World!* program on a `Fedora Linux` system through the `terminal` using `gcc`, and get the following:

```
[abder-rahman@Abder Desktop]$ gcc hello.cpp

hello.cpp:1:22: fatal error: iostream.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

Why is that? What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the tutorial or book you follow is very old, I suggest you try to find something more modern (and by more modern, anything written the last ten years would probably be better).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to get iostream.h](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698267/where-to-get-iostream-h)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should compile C++ programs with `g++`, not `gcc`.
2. There's no `iostream.h` header in standard C++. It's `iostream` (though `iostream.h` may be offered for backwards compatibility with ancient C++ code).

Answer (score 3):

use g++ instead of gcc

```
g++ hello.cpp
```